# How can I create an lxc guest that communicates with the host?

Tags: networking, lxc, network-bridge, lxd

I'm trying to set up a guest lxc with communication between it and the host system but I have had no success as yet.

How can I set it up?

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run the `lxd init` command, and follow the questions, it will set up a bridge between the host and the lxc containers.
On my computer:

```
lxdbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:53:ad:4e:69:40  
          inet addr:10.20.30.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.0
```

when you start up a container, it will get an ip address via dhcp from the lxc services.
You can find out the ip address with `lxc list` command:

```
+-----------+---------+---------------------+------+------------+-----------+
|   NAME    |  STATE  |        IPV4         | IPV6 |    TYPE    | SNAPSHOTS |
+-----------+---------+---------------------+------+------------+-----------+
| ubu16-ssl | RUNNING | 10.20.30.186 (eth0) |      | PERSISTENT | 0         |
+-----------+---------+---------------------+------+------------+-----------+
```